# Replace a string in list of strings with Haskell

Tags: haskell

i'am trying to create function that replace a given string in list of strings for exemple **remplacer 'a' ["leaf","cacao"]** gives a list  **["le f","c co"]**

with Haskell from this code :

```
remplacer k = map(\c -> if c== k then ' '; else c)
```

once i do the call

```
map remplacer "\r" ["abcd\r","alo\r"]
```

i got
*Couldn't match  type 'char' with '[char]'*

or result should be

```
["abcd ","alo "]
```

Comment: `remPlacer` is taking chars but you are using it on strings ([char])

Comment: how do i need to change the code to let it accept strings?

if i change it to : remplacer = map(\c -> if c== 'a' then ' '; else c) it works fine

Comment: You can't replace a `String` in a list of `String`s with Haskell, lists are homogeneous.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the types:

```
map                :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
"\r"               :: [Char] -- Which is equivalent to String
["abcd\r","alo\r"] :: [[Char]] -- Same as [String]
remplacer          :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
```

Notice remplacer takes Char, not [Char]. But replacing "\r" with '\r' alone won't work, because then we are making the first argument of map remplacer and the second '\r', in other words `((map remplacer) '\r')` . This will not type check. What we want is make `ramplacer '\r'` the first argument:

```
λ> map (remplacer '\r') ["abcd\r","alo\r"]
["abcd ","alo "]
```

Edit: I couldn't resist exploring your how  `map remplacer ".."` would work. For amusement, check how different of a function it is:

```
λ> :t map remplacer "ab"
map remplacer "ab" :: [[Char] -> [Char]]
λ>  ($  "abc") <$> (map remplacer ['a', 'b'])
[" bc","a c"]
```

`$` is simply `\f a -> f a`, regular function application. The original question/answer uses map twice, this one uses map three times.

Comment: i tried your solution i have got : lexical error in string/character literal at end of input

Comment: do you mean `map (remplacer '\r') ["abcd\r","alo\r"]`?

Comment: Edited the question with result I get in ghci.

Comment: i actually need to replace a string in list containing multiple strings. i don't know how your code can take do that. sorry im new with haskell

Comment: If you have examples of inputs and outputs I suggest you add them to the question.

Comment: i did you can check it

Comment: Just did, that's what my answer does, isn't it?

Comment: i do not understand the ($  "abc") <$>  
is it possible to keep this syntax : (map remplacer ['a', 'b']) ["abc","cdef"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237975/discussion-between-maher-kebaier-and-pedrofurla).

Comment: Your answer is this one `map (remplacer '\r') ["abcd\r","alo\r"]`

Comment: ok is it possible that the argument '\r' can be a string (ex: "En") ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire